# if and else statement both executed within onclicklistener for linearlayout

Tags: java, android, conditional-statements, android-linearlayout, onclicklistener

I have this onclicklistener for my LinearLayout:

```
   LinearLayout closedbets = (LinearLayout) findViewById (R.id.closedbetslayout);
    closedbets.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            TextView closedtxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.settledbetstxtview);
            closedtxt.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#09AD21"));
            TextView openbetstxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.openbetstxtview);
            openbetstxt.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#B4B5AE"));
            listwriter = getListwriter();
            if (listwriter.size() ==0) {
                Log.d("EMPTY LISTWRITER","empty");
                TextView emptybet = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nobetstxtbox);
                emptybet.setText("None of your bets have been settled yet.");
                emptybet.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            else {
                PopulateList();
            }
        }
    });
```

The issue is that even when the listwriter is empty and the Log is executed, for some reason the `PopulateList();` method gets executed and I get a `nullpointerexception` in the adapter which is used to populate the list since the listwriter is empty.

LOGCAT

```
06-29 18:51:08.492  28394-28394/com.example.albert.bettertipapp D/EMPTY LISTWRITER﹕ empty
06-29 18:51:08.512  28394-28394/com.example.albert.bettertipapp D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
06-29 18:51:08.512  28394-28394/com.example.albert.bettertipapp W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4172cda0)
06-29 18:51:08.532  28394-28394/com.example.albert.bettertipapp E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.albert.bettertipapp, PID: 28394
    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
            at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
            at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
            at com.example.albert.betterapp.DisplayAllBets$MyListAdapter.getView(DisplayAllBets.java:764)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2733)
            at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1274)
            at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1186)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17396)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5365)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1410)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17396)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:719)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:455)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17396)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5365)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17396)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5365)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1410)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17396)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5365)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2505)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17396)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2175)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1316)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1513)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1200)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6401)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:803)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:603)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:573)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:789)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5335)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Is that the only place `PopulateList` is called? Use a debugger to track thru the code

Comment: It happens when I click on the closedbetlistview only, no where else

Comment: I've not seen all the code, but I think that `listwriter` won't cause NPE as it is initialized already, even if it is of zero length. All code would be preferrable, as well as logcat with stacktrace

Comment: its returning an empty arraylist, but I know it enters the conditional because i get this logged `D/EMPTY LISTWRITER﹕ empty
 D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4172cda0)
E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main` meaning the very next thing that happens is the nullpointerexception following the log

Comment: edit your question and add the full stacktrace of the exception

Comment: @Blackbelt just made the edit

Comment: the problem is the Adapter. Post the adapter

Comment: Above code is in Adapter?? There is some problem in PopulateList()  Are you using  for reloading adapter?. post your adapter code.

Comment: The adapter isn't the problem, the problem is that the adapter gets called. The adapter is called within PopulateList and nowhere else, that's why it shouldn't be called at all. The error occurs because the listwriter is empty and I'm calling listwriter.get(position) in the getView method so obviously it creates an exception

Comment: Yes @KishanVaghela but the adapter should not be called in this case.

Comment: Are you passing listwriter for Adapter? If yes, then you should make notify adapter after assigned It (i.e. Above your if condition). Adapter may using old list.

Comment: I would take out the call to `PopulateList` and replace it with a log statement logging the number of elements in `listWriter`.  That would definitively tell you if that code branch is actually being executed and why.

Comment: @nasch I solved it by moving the `PopulateList` method to the top of the activity. Not sure why, but that seems to work. I didn't post it as an answer since I'm not sure what the logic behind it is

Comment: Where in the source file a method is defined makes no difference (assuming it stays in the same class), so you must have done something else as well.  Glad it's solved though.